# Riemann sum using midpoint

Tags: calculus, analysis, riemann-integration

I am asked to calculate this integral $\int_{-1}^{5}(1+3x)dx$ using the Riemann sum definition with $\Delta x = \Delta x_{i} = \frac{b\ - \ a}{n}$ (as in all the intervals in the x axis are evenly spaced) and using the midpoint of each $\Delta x_{i}$, as in $c_{i} = \frac{1}{2}(x_{i} + x_{i + 1}) \ (i=1,2,3, \cdots, n - 1). $

Is it right to say that $c_{i}$ will be equal to $\frac{i\Delta x + a + i\Delta x + a + \Delta x}{2}$, with $x_{i} = i\Delta x + a $ and $x_{i+1} = i\Delta x + a + \Delta x$? Because that's where I think I'm making a mistake.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: your expression for $c_i$ seems correct and it simplifies to $i\Delta x +a+\frac{\Delta x}{2}$

Comment: I end up getting a 42/n (42 is the correct answer) after factoring out the sum, which goes to 0 when I take the limit. Could you try to carry the sum and see if you get the same answer as I do? Maybe I'm making some algebra mistake.

Comment: In $\frac{b-a}{n}$What it the value of $n=?$

Comment: Arbitrarily big...?